# Show that $E(K)/2E(K)$ is finite

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, torsion-groups

I am revisiting the weak Mordell-Weil theorem, which says that $E(K)/mE(K)$ is finite, where $K$ is a number field. I am just wondering that is there a way to prove this statement for $m=2$ using Selmer group (that works for all number fields $K$)? Thanks very much.

Comment: There is a chapter about this in Silverman AEC, do you like it?

Comment: Hi, I did saw a discussion of the case $m=2$ in Chapter 10 (after Theorem 10.1), but I just didn't see how this discussion is related to showing $E(K)/2E(K)$ is finite.

Comment: That's chapter VIII

Comment: Yes I did remember that Chapter 8 mentions it but I don't think it uses Selmer group in the proof.

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. In X.4 he is proving that the Selmer group is finite.

Comment: In the proof he is using part of chapter VIII global proof, that's why he says at the beginning of chapter X that finiteness of Selmer group is quite the same as weak Mordell.

Comment: I see. That makes sense to me and I will revisit Chapter 8 then. Thanks so much for your help!